# cant reach internet from instances in icehouse

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am having issues in reaching the internet from any of the instances created on the open-stack dashboard. Below are additional details

I have created 2 instances with following IP's. Instance1 - 10.0.0.2(Floating IP: 192.168.2.2) Instance2- 10.0.0.3(Floating IP: 192.168.2.3)

Host IP: 192.168.2.50

I can ping the GW 192.168.2.1 or the floating IP's 192.168.2.2/3 from the instances but i cant ping the host IP or the internet from instances. Same applies from host side as i cant ping any of the floating IP's from the host.

I currently do not have any FW rules on host and on the instances i am allowing all traffic.

Can someone please help me with this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several issues here. First, you need to make sure that your security group allows ICMP - this will allow you to ping your floating IPs. Without it, ping won't work.

Can you ssh into the VMs? If so, the security group ICMP rule is probably the problem.

In general, ping is not a reliable tool in many cloud environments. It is often blocked.

Now, regarding accessing the network outside the cloud. Try to

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

It is possible that there is a problem with your DNS configuration. Try to

```
telnet <some web server> 80
```

If this works then your openstack subnet is probably missing the DNS server IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Set Security Groups, adding ingress rules to ICMP, SSH and also HTTP and HTTPS.

Set DNS, in the private Network, editing private-subnet to add a DNS Name Servers (8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, etc).

And in ESXi and Ubuntu 16, I set proxy arp and iptables:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ens160/proxy_arp
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
```